# can we print current value of table data in mapping in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, react-hooks

I have a list of objects named favs.
I have used mapping to show them into table form and also i have attached a button.In that button I have created a onClick function which will print the current name (using console.log() ).
but when i click on any button ,it always prints the first element of that list.
can any one look into my code and tell what am i doing wrong? thanks in advance :)
**fav list**

```
const [favs, setFavs] = useState([{
    name:"node"
    },
  {
    name:"react-js"
  },
  {
    name:"node js"
  }])
```

**HasFav.js File**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DeleteConfirm from "./DeleteConfirm";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const HasFavs = ({favs,handleDelete}) => {

  const handDel =(e)=>{
    console.log(e)
    handleDelete(e)
  }

  return (
    <span>
      <h1>Welcome to Favorite NPM Packages</h1>

      <Link to="/">Add Fav </Link>
       
     
      <div>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Package Name</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
       
          {
            favs.map((favorite)=>{
              
              return (
                <tr key={favorite.name}>
                  <td>
                    {favorite.name}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                   
                    <button onClick={()=>console.log(favorite.name)}>press</button> 
                    <DeleteConfirm  value={`${favorite.name}`} handleDelete={handDel}  />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              )
            })
          }
        
        </table>
      </div>
    </span>
  );
};

export default HasFavs;
```

**DeleteConfirm.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const DeleteConfirm = ({value,handleDelete}) => {

  
  const del= (e)=>{
  
    console.log(value)
    console.log(e.target)
    handleDelete()
  }



  return (
    <div>
<button type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
<i class='fa fa-trash' style={{color:'#555553'}}></i>

</button>

<div className="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div className="modal-content">
      
      <div className="modal-body">
        Are you sure You want to delete?
      </div>
      <div className="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" value={value} onClick={del}>Yes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default DeleteConfirm
```

it always prints the first obejct of favs.

[image]

Comment: It's not printing the first object of favs, its just printing the node element of the button which is button `Yes` ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap this console.log(favorite.name) into braces {console.log(favorite.name)}